# iphone - asynchronous upload and download operation freezes the UI

Tags: iphone, ios, nsoperation

In my app , I want to achieve multiple uploads and downloads using Websocket protocol.

For that purpose , I have made class called `Engine` , `Upload` and `Download`

`Engine` - creates a `operationQueue` and `maximumConcurrentOperation` is 3 .

`Upload` and `Download` - subclass of `NSOperation` and override the `main` method . In `main` method , both the class have following statements

```
Engine.m
-(id)init
{
     if(self = [super init])
     {
          opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
          opQueue.maximumConcurrentOperationCount = 3 ;
     }
}
-(void)startUploadWithPath:(NSString *)file
{
    Upload *up = [[Upload alloc] initWithPath:file];
    [opQueue addOperation:up];
}

-(void)startDownloadWithPath:(NSString *)file
{
    Download *down = [[Upload alloc] initWithPath:file];
    [opQueue addOperation:down];
}

Upload.m and Download.m
-(void)main
{
   //start transfering data to server

   while(workCompleted != YES)
    {
        // wait()
    } 

    // when work completed
    //insertIntoDB();
}
```

**Problem :**  When I try to upload first video , then it works fine . Immidiately if I try to upload second video , then also it works fine . When I try to upload third video(i.e when I select video from gallery and video compression has not began yet) , the application freeze . The application becomes active only when one of the two previous video upload is completed .

Why does the application freeze even if `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is 3 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've posted absolutely no real code at all, yet you're asking 5 questions that are extremely specific to what the code you wrote does. Each of those questions should be a totally separate question on SO.

Comment: Okay .. I am removing some questions

Answer (score 0):

try uploading videos in parallel, for example like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(inParallel) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

 ...

-(void)inParallel {

NSLog(@"occurs in parallel");

 }
```

this should not freeze the UI but it is worth trying